# Visualize route knowing GPS locations

Tags: silverlight, mapping, bing-maps

I have data from GPS tracking device. Data looks like pings every 5-15 minutes containing Lat/Lon.

I can display points on map and that will kind of show how object was moving but it is not ideal. I'd like to "connect the dots" and show route. I realize that it may not be accurate, but still.

So, what is the best way to show line betwen 2 points on bing map? I don't want straight line, I want driving line.

I was thinking about navigation API, but what if I have like 200 points?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will answer my own question with my own findings..

1. When I have 200 points - map doing OK displaying those. Map doing fine displaying 1000 points on my PC. After 2000 points it starts to feel sluggish.
2. Connecting points can be done with PolyLine and it is somewhat works. But this is straight line.
3. Having nice driving line between points can be done using API like shown here:
   http://www.microsoft.com/maps/isdk/silverlight/#MapControlInteractiveSdk.Tutorials.Services.Route
   However, in my case I need to do multiple calls since API accepts up to 25 points. So, 1000/25 = 40 API calls to get data. And, this data will have HUGE arrays of points so polyline follows roads. Performance becomes an issue.

In my case - I went with custom pushpins to show locations and didn't connect those. It give OK visual and OK performance